# Frequency of key in group

Tags: r, frequency

Given I have a dataframe `df` like this containing the columns `Key` and `User`.

```
Key  User  
1   Bob  
2   Tobi  
1   Bob  
3   Bob  
4   Bob  
5   Bob  
6   Tobi  
5   Bob
```

I want to create a new column whichs value is calculated like this:

> Frequency of this rows key in the dataset / number of rows where user
>   equals the user in this row

Shown on this example, it would look like this:

```
Key  User  Freq
1   Bob    2/6
2   Tobi   1/2
1   Bob    2/6
3   Bob    1/6
4   Bob    1/6
5   Bob    2/6
6   Tobi   1/2
5   Bob    2/6
```

I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem in R, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Why is `6   Tobi   1/6` not `6   Tobi   1/2`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one approach using `table`, `prop.table`, and `merge`. Assuming your data.frame is called "mydf":

```
> merge(mydf, as.data.frame(prop.table(table(mydf), margin = 2)))
  Key User      Freq
1   1  Bob 0.3333333
2   1  Bob 0.3333333
3   2 Tobi 0.5000000
4   3  Bob 0.1666667
5   4  Bob 0.1666667
6   5  Bob 0.3333333
7   5  Bob 0.3333333
8   6 Tobi 0.5000000
```

Answer (score 5):

If your data set is called dat using `ave` is one approach:

```
## dat <- read.table(text="Key  User  
## 1   Bob  
## 2   Tobi  
## 1   Bob  
## 3   Bob  
## 4   Bob  
## 5   Bob  
## 6   Tobi  
## 5   Bob", header=TRUE)

dat$Freq <- paste(with(dat, ave(Key, Key, FUN=length)), 
    with(dat, ave(as.character(User), User, FUN=length)), sep="/")

##   Key User Freq
## 1   1  Bob  2/6
## 2   2 Tobi  1/2
## 3   1  Bob  2/6
## 4   3  Bob  1/6
## 5   4  Bob  1/6
## 6   5  Bob  2/6
## 7   6 Tobi  1/2
## 8   5  Bob  2/6
```

**Break it down a bit**

This gives the freqs by Key:

```
## + > with(dat, ave(Key, Key, FUN=length))
## [1] 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 2
```

This gives the denominator freqs by User(though one of yours is 2 and I'm not sure if I missed something):

```
## > with(dat, ave(as.character(User), User, FUN=length))
## [1] "6" "2" "6" "6" "6" "6" "2" "6"
```

Then I paste the two together.

***Edit-per Ananda Mahto comment:***

If you're after an actual value (decimal likely) use the same form as above but withdivision as the final step rather than paste:

```
dat$Freq2 <- with(dat, ave(Key, Key, FUN=length))/ 
    with(dat, as.numeric(ave(as.character(User), User, FUN=length)))
```

Comment: I think this is a very literal interpretation. I'm assuming they're looking for the actual value ("I want to create a new column whichs value is calculated like this"). Nevertheless, +1!

Comment: @Ananda Mahto I think you're probably correct.  I added a bit to do that.

Comment: @AnandaMahto and Tyler you can also use the `fractions` function in `MASS` to have numeric fractions which you can do arithmetic on, e.g. `require(MASS); fractions(0.1111111111111)*3` gives `[1] 1/3`

Comment: @SimonO101, I already know about the `fractions` function, but is there a way for it to generate non-simplified fractions? In a way, if we were going the fractions approach, "2/6" has a different meaning from "1/3" in this question, even if they are both the same value.

Comment: @AnandaMahto great question. Post it?!